# What does a "Resource temporarily unavailable" error mounting a filesystem mean?

Tags: mount

What does this error mean, and how can I solve it?

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/pzj/B8082EA0082E5D9E: Command-line
mount -t "ntfs" -o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
"/dev/sda4" "/media/pzj/B8082EA0082E5D9E"' exited with non-zero exit
status  18: Failed to write lock '/dev/sda4': Resource temporarily
unavailable Error opening '/dev/sda4': Resource temporarily
unavailable Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Resource temporarily
unavailable  (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

Here is a snap of the Disk via disks.

[image: Image Snap]

**Edit:**

**Output of sudo fdisk -l**

pzj@cloudz:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for pzj:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
01F58508-AB5F-4912-9A0A-2CB7F87AD409

`Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type`
`/dev/sda1     2048    616447     614400  300M Windows recovery environment`    
`/dev/sda2      616448     821247     204800  100M EFI System`
`/dev/sda3   821248     1083391     262144  128M Microsoft reserved`
`/dev/sda4  1083392    1953523711 1952440320  931G Microsoft basic data
```

**Output of mount**

```
pzj@cloudz:~$ mount
/dev/sdb5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755,size=1024)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
/dev/sdb4 on /var type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,noexec,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=pzj)
/dev/sda1 on /media/pzj/Recovery type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
pzj@cloudz:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! "Resource temporarily unavailable" is what it means. solving it depends on why. Can you mount it with Disk utility or does it show as mounted? If a low level process is in use on /dev/sda4 it will be unavailable for mounting until that process completes. (dd or dc3dd come to mind). Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount` to your question to help us help you.

Comment: @ElderGeek Editing to include information.

Answer (score 0):

The what is evident by the error, as to why the drive is unavailable , based on the disk utility output **the drive appears to be failing**. You also appear to be dual booting Windows. **If fast-start is enabled under Windows *(the default)* the file system is unavailable due to the hibernation file Windows leaves there**. This is actually for your protection. If you were to make changes to the file system with Ubuntu while Windows is in hibernation status (fast-boot), you would lose those changes upon rebooting (resuming) Windows.

The first thing to try is disabling fast-boot from windows. This should allow you to mount the drive with Ubuntu.

**I recommend replacement of the drive ASAP and insuring that you have current backups of all your critical data.**

Source: Experience

Comment: I can't boot into windows. Say's no operating installed.

Comment: If you have data on the partition you are trying to mount you may find this useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: LEt me explain: I have Windows 8.1 Pro installed on the 1TB. I shutdown then try to boot up again and I get the error *no OS detected* or something similar to that extent. I try mounting the OS in ubuntu where the error outlined in my question was produced. Windows was not hibernated. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: No clarification required. I believe I understand completely. I stand by my answer although I understand that you believe Windows 8.1 was not hibernated. Fast startup is the default in windows 8 and 8.1 so unless you turned it off explicitly you have a hibernation file on the drive: Further research: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: Repairing your Windows 8.1 boot is a second step and you should recover your data first.

Comment: What is your source for the claim that " If fast-start is enabled under Windows (the default) the file system is reported as unavailable due to the hibernation file Windows leaves there."? I have never seen "Resource temporarily unavailable" as a consequence of Win 8 hubernation. Rather, I have always seen a different error message that explicitly mentions hibernation.

Comment: @ignis Regardless of the error message you see, I think you'll agree that the file system is unavailable when hibernated. I think that we can further agree that when a drive is failing self-test it should be replaced. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @ElderGeek Please give your source or remove the claims from the answer, this smells like stating your personal interpretation as if it were facts, which would be harmful and would make misinformation.

Comment: @ElderGeek System commands generally return the same error message on the same error condition, so that an advanced user can quickly diagnose a problem by memorizing the strings. Now either you do know for a fact that "if hibernation or fast start is enabled then it is reported as textually 'unavailable' by the mount command", which I have never seen on my machine or any other Ubuntu users' machines, or you don't, do not waste our time into arguing your personal interpretation and help us spread real experience or factual knowledge. Thanks

Comment: @ignis rephrased answer due to your semantic concerns.. I'm sorry if you feel I wasted your time answering a question. Please feel free to provide your own answer.